# iOS Contact Detail Selection

Tags: ios, properties, contacts

Below image is share contact in WhatsApp.My question is: is it a default ios multiple property picker view or custom view developed WhatsApp? if default view please help me to develop that UI.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a default view developed by WhatsApp.

You can achieve this functionality by using UITableView.

Create an object of UITableView and create custom cell.

Hope this helps.